# Ember.js - Update CSS width based on an object property

Tags: css, ember.js, observable

As mentioned in [@andorov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32593118/565877), the OP's ideal code (`<div style="width:{{model.width}}">` now pretty much just works as of Ember 1.10

> I am new to Ember.js, and I am finding it difficult to dynamically
>   change CSS. Here is an example to explain what I mean:
>
> ```
> var App = Em.Application.create();
>
> App.MyObj=Em.Object.extend({
>     objWidth:10
> });
>
> App.objController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
>     content: [],
>   createObj: function(){
>       var obj = App.MyObj.create();
>       this.pushObject(obj);
>   }
> });
> ```
>
> The code below doesn't work, but it explains my goal. Using a
>   Handlebars template, I want to accomplish this:
>
> ```
> {{#each obj in App.objController}}
>      <div style="width:{{obj.objWidth}}"></div>
> {{/each}}
> ```
>
> In other words, I just want to have the width of the `<div>` update
>   when the `objWidth` property is changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `style` property has to be bound with `bindAttr`, passing the **style as a whole**, not just one of the properties, as it doesn't understand that. This property only gives you access to the style as a string, targeting the immediate element. It's not possible to bind to a property of the style if you define it like that.

So [here's my sugestion](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/ftWZ6/): I've created a couple of "model" classes like the following, implementing a property that returns the width in pixels:

```
var WidthEnabledModel = Em.Object.extend({
    width: 100,
    unit: "px",
    widthString: function() {
        return 'width: %@%@'.fmt(this.width, this.unit);
    }.property('width', 'unit')            
});

App.SampleModel = WidthEnabledModel.extend({
    itemName: ''
});
```

Then, for each item in your collection I'm binding that property to the `style` attribute:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sample">
    <div id="sample_area" style="width: 250px;">
    {{#each thing in controller.content}}
      <div class="item" {{bindAttr style="thing.widthString"}}>
          {{thing.itemName}}<br />
          {{thing.widthString}}
      </div>
    {{/each}}
    <div>
</script>
```

Follow the example with full code I've made at jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/ftWZ6/

**Edit:**
I've made some changes in the fiddle to add more feature, but the part to set the width stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your original solution `style="{{dynamicStyleAttribute}}"` now works, with the new bound attribute syntax -
http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_bound-attribute-syntax

You would need to append a `px` to the value for `width:300px`, and call `Ember.String.htmlSafe('your string')` on it as well.

Note that there are still some unresolved issues:
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10783
https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10870

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a view and binding it to the controller?

For example:

**In your Javascript:**

```
App.objView = Ember.View.extend({
    contentBinding : 'App.objController',
    widthBinding : 'content.width'
});
```

**In your Handlebars:**

```
{{#each Ember.App.objController}}
    {{#view Ember.App.objView contentBinding="this"}}
        <div style="width: {{width}};"></div>
    {{/view}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't seem to work. It seems that you can't insert a variable into the `style` value using handlebars.

Here is what the HTML ends up as using your suggestion:
`style="width: <script id='metamorph-6-start' type='text/x-placeholder'></script><script id='metamorph-6-end' type='text/x-placeholder'></script>;"`